# Происхождение слова "намедни"

Tags: этимология

Намедни - как я понимаю, это "недавно". А интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого слова. Как я понимаю, тут есть приставка "на-". Тогда - на какой "медни"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наме/дни = на днях.  Мне кажется, слово это сходно по составу с другим наречием - *севодни*.

> А. А. Боратынский. Письма (1785-1802)
> **Севодни** я получил известие, что флот из Англии пришол; но братья остались там (ибо им должно более быть) я еще не получил от них писем, только знаю от курьера что брат Богдан в Северном море а Илья уехал в Северную Америку.
> А. С. Пушкин. Роман в письмах (1829)
> **Намедни** сочинил я надпись к портрету княжны Ольги (за что Лиза очень мило бранила меня)...
> (Нацкорпус)

Answer (score 1):

Этимология: "оными дни" = "на этих днях".

Уточним значение слова: "намедни", "на днях" значит недавно, но НЕ сегодня, а днями раньше. 
Если хотели сказать "недавно сегодня", говорили "давеча", "даве". -- "Поди дале, где был даве" (В.Даль)

Нынче мы не используем никаких слов для этого (почему?), и "намедни", и "давеча" звучат архаично. Да и "нынче" тоже :-)